# XCode: "Module not found" for Toast_Swift in only one view controller

Tags: swift, xcode7

I'm trying to import Toast Swift into a few View Controllers of a project and it works fine in ALL BUT one view Controller.  In that one, XCode is telling me "No such module right on the line where I'm importing it.  Like I said, it works fine in all my other View Controllers.

Here's what the top of the problematic view controller looks like:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import Toast_Swift
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

class ScanDetailViewController: UIViewController, PiechartDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
```

And here's what Xcode is throwing up:

[image]

I've cleaned my build folder and confirmed this is working in other view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was creating an instance of the misbehaving VC in a VC that was being presented modally over the VC in question.